# Eclipse error when installing in new laptop

Tags: java, eclipse

Hi I always have used `eclipse` in the past but recently I tried to download `eclipse` for my new laptop and it keeps giving me this error.

> ...... ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf code=1002 HTTP
>   Proxy Authentication Required:
>   http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/201706281000/content.xml.xz
>   ERROR: org.eclipse.ecf.identity code=0 Proxy Authentication Required
>   .....

- How can I fix this?

Comment: You chopped off the necessary error message in the middle. Looks like there's a proxy on your network that requires authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a proxy, or are unable to download it due to not having a proxy specified

try running one of these commands in your command line before downloading:

```
set http_proxy=http://your_proxy:your_port set 
http_proxy=http://username:password@your_proxy:your_port set 
https_proxy=https://your_proxy:your_port set 
https_proxy=https://username:password@your_proxy:your_port
```

Comment: How will setting shell variables help? Are you assuming Windows?

Comment: Yes, I assume he is running windows